# what is the meaning of ({ a } = b); in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
let b = { a: 123123123 };
try {
  ({ a } = b); <<< what is the meaning of () 

} catch (error) {}
console.log({'a':a})
```

why this script work, what is the meaning of () in  try-catch .

the `{ a } = b` is wrong but  `({ a } = b)`  is correct and the variable will go out of try-catch and give new value to a.

if there are a function in () may be a IIFE, if in expressions the () is a Grouping operator.and in my example,what is the meaning of ()

Comment: [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). `()` are needed here to prevent `{}` from being parsed as the parenthesis of a block. You wouldn't need `()` if `a` wasn't available in the scope. If that was the case, you would write this statement as: `const { a } = b;`

Comment: A `{` at the start of the line is interpreted as a code block, so using grouping `()` ensures it's treated as destructuring.

Comment: Is there another `a` declared in a higher scope?

Comment: @zero298 it's not necessary, because the block is treated as an expression, hence `a` is implitly assigned, although I think `a` in this case is an implicit global.

Answer (score 4):

A pair of parenthesis force the contents to be treated as an expression instead of a statement.

This causes the `{` to be seen at the start of an object or dereferencing structure (the latter in this case) instead of a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).